# Exception from android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate() in Android NDK application (Android 6.0 only)

Tags: android, exception, android-ndk, native

I recently updated Android Studio and all the SDK libraries (June 2019), and suddenly some of my users started experiencing this crash at the application startup.

For what I can see, it is only happening on Android 6.0.

The application is an Android Native App, using the NDK and the `app_glue` base classes, build in compiledSDK=26.

Did someone else has experienced something similar?

I don't have an Android 6.0 phone. I tried to create a Virtual Device, but I'm not able to replicate the issue on the virtual device. 
It is working perfectly for thousand of other players (Android 7, 8, 9)

This is the Exception call stack =================================

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
(ActivityThread.java:3253)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3349)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 (ActivityThread.java:221)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1794)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7224)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate (NativeActivity.java:170)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6876)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3206)
```

---

UPDATE: 
This issue arises only with the latest **Gradle version : 3.4.1**
When I revert back to **3.2.1**, the crash disappear. 
Gradle seems to do something differently that produce the app crash in Android 6.0.

Comment: This debug text is not enough because the "IllegalArgumentException" occurred INSIDE the just new/created Activity probably in one of its "on...()" methods. Please check for something that could raise that Exception (maybe you throw this exception? or maybe some library?)

Answer (score 2):

If you check [`NativeActivity` implementation in AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/58b8b24256bdc2b613b7fda9151845ed9898a4c7/core/java/android/app/NativeActivity.java) in [this commit from 5 years ago](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/58b8b24256bdc2b613b7fda9151845ed9898a4c7) (next one is from 3 years and 7 months ago, should be past 6.0), you find that [line 170](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/58b8b24256bdc2b613b7fda9151845ed9898a4c7/core/java/android/app/NativeActivity.java#170) throws an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
mNativeHandle = loadNativeCode(path, funcname, Looper.myQueue(),
        getAbsolutePath(getFilesDir()), getAbsolutePath(getObbDir()),
        getAbsolutePath(getExternalFilesDir(null)),
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, getAssets(), nativeSavedState);
if (mNativeHandle == 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to load native library: " + path);
}
```

This means is not able to find your native library (or some referenced library), or maybe is failing to load it for some reason.

I'll check with Cmd-shift-A -> "Analyze APK..." to see if all the architectures are present for all the native libraries. One possible problem could be that for some reason some of the architectures it's being excluded, and because of that is working on most of the devices, but in some is failing.

Comment: This seems like logical and plausible explanation. I will do the check and report any results. Thanks for your reply,

Comment: Hope it helps to find the root cause.

Comment: That exception is raised from this line :

`String path = null;
File libraryFile = new File(ai.applicationInfo.nativeLibraryDir, System.mapLibraryName(libname));
if (libraryFile.exists()) { path = libraryFile.getPath(); }
if (path == null) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find native library: " + libname); } `
It is a simply check for a file exist. 
I still don't understand why this happens only in some Android 6.0.

Comment: The file is trying to find is your native library. There are multiple reasons why this can happen, one being mixed library architectures in a 64-bit environment. Basically it means you have to have all the libraries in all the supported architectures. For example, if you're compiling only a 32-bit arch of your library, but including another library that has both, 32 and 64-bit, load could fail. See: https://xrubio.com/2015/09/android-compatibility-with-32-bit-libraries-on-a-64-bit-device/ and https://xrubio.com/2018/02/android-compatibility-with-32-bit-libraries-on-a-64-bit-device-updated/

Comment: I found a work around for my issue, is to revert back to the previous gradle version : **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'**. The faulty Gradle was **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'**. I don't know if Gradle is fully responsible for the Android 6.0 crash, but reverting to the previous version seem to avoid the issue. I will try to communicate with the gradle team about this. Thanks for your help.